# MySQL join select from foreign table name in cell

Tags: mysql, select, join

I am having 2 tables with identical structure (there will be more), in which I will have 2 columns referring to table and primary key of another table:

```
TABLE 1:
    id value      exttable  extid
    =============================
    1  val_1_1    0         0
    2  val_1_2    0         0
    3  NULL       2         5
    4  val_1_4    0         0
    5  val_1_5    0         0

TABLE 2:
    id value      exttable  extid
    =============================
    1  val_2_1    0         0
    2  val_2_2    0         0
    3  val_2_3    0         0
    4  val_2_4    0         0
    5  val_2_5    0         0
```

I'd like to make a select on table 1, which reads the **exttable** and **extid** columns values and referes to the other table. So my output shall be like this:

```
OUTPUT:
    id val
    ==========
    1  val_1_1
    2  val_1_2
    3  val_2_5
    4  val_1_4
    5  val_1_5
```

I'm aware that a circular reference can cause trouble but I will avoid this in a different way.

Comment: IS your target dataset correct? Because this is a single UNION

Comment: In general, you have a problem with a data structure when you have multiple tables with the same columns.  You should have an addition "tableid" column and put all the data in a single table.

Comment: Yes you are right. Having the same structure on 2 tables is not smart. Actually the structure is not the same, but similar, so I simplified it for example matters.

Answer (score 1):

You should be putting all this data in a single table with an additional column, which I will call "tableid".  If you had this, you could do:

```
select t.id,
       (case when t.exttable <> 0 then t1.value else t2.value end) as value,
       (case when t.exttable <> 0 then t1.exttable else t2.exttable end) as exttable,
       (case when t.exttable <> 0 then t1.extid else t2.extid end) as extid
from table t left outer join
     table t2
     on t.exttable = t2.tableid and
        t.extid = t2.id;
```

Because your data is in the wrong format, you can do this more painfully with a `union all`:

```
select t.id,
       (case when t.exttable <> 0 then t1.value else t2.value end) as value,
       (case when t.exttable <> 0 then t1.exttable else t2.exttable end) as exttable,
       (case when t.exttable <> 0 then t1.extid else t2.extid end) as extid
from ((select 'table1' as tableid, t.* from table1 t) union all
      (select 'table2' as tableid, t.* from table2 t)
     ) t left outer join
     ((select 'table1' as tableid, t.* from table1 t) union all
      (select 'table2' as tableid, t.* from table2 t)
     ) t2
     on t.exttable = t2.tableid and
        t.extid = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work otherwise some a little changes needed in this query.
Try this...

```
select * from (select id,value from TABLE 1 where value !=NULL UNION 
select TABLE 1.id,TABLE 2.value from TABLE 2,TABLE 1 where TABLE 1.value =NULL 
and TABLE 1.extid=TABLE 2.id ) as results order by id
```

Comment: No this will not work, because table name of TABLE 2 has to be read out of the cell - so it's dynamic. I will have more then 2 tables, so I can't hardcode it to only 2.